# How to Fit a Thru Axle Road Bike into Elite Nove Force Home Trainer

Tags: trainer, through-axle, indoor

After a lot of research, I've settled on buying [Elite Novo Force](https://www.elite-it.com/en/products/home-trainers/classic-trainers/novo-force) as my home trainer. I know its pros 'n cons and this question focuses on something else. The problem I am having now is that I don't understand how can I attach my [Cube Attain Pro](https://cube-bikes.ca/2021/attain-pro-road-bike/) road bike to it.

My bike has a thru axle and Elite offers [various options.](https://www.elite-it.com/en/products/home-trainers/ecosystem-accessories) I've checked them and their respected data sheets on which adapter I specifically need but I'm baffled as what to buy or even if I need one since it may also be included in the box with the trainer. I also checked YouTube throughly but there are a multitude of options and not all of them are up-to-date.

Could you please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I find my trainer is not kind to any bike I put on it. My sweat drips right into the drivetrain, any rigorous (standing) pedaling puts a higher-than-normal strain on the seat-stays (IMO), and you can forget about the tires lasting. I'd suggest an older bike (ie, the one the Cube replaced) or finding a cheap second-hand roadie. Heavy department-store BSOs can actually be useful for this, they just need to spin and shift.

Comment: @MarcBernier You should really use [trainer-specific tyres](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/81950/is-an-indoor-trainer-tyre-required-with-a-magnetic-powered-trainer). I find normal tyres to deteriorate very quickly, one has a lot of small black pieces of rubber around the braking cylinder with normal tyres. I also suggest to have a towel at hand or over your handlebars. Then you can use a good bike without big issues. Maybe not a superbike, but the cube is not a superbike.

Comment: @MarcBernier I also ordered a sweat net. That should also be handy since it runs  vertically along your bike. Plus, a towel like Vladimir mentioned and perhaps a ventilator should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thru axle adapter https://www.elite-it.com/en/products/home-trainers/ecosystem-accessories/thru-axle-adapter should do it. You have a 12x142 mm thru axle.

The trainer web page quotes the part number of the required adapter:

> To fit your bike with thru axles to your trainer you can shop the
> required adapter (cod. 1020008) on shopelite-it.com.

The current compatibility sheet unfortunately does not list Novo Force, but this declaration should be enough. The [shop description](https://www.shopelite-it.com/en/sensors-adaptors-and-heart-rates/adapters/adapter-with-spacer-for-hometrainers-for-10-mm-and-12-mm-diameter-thru-axle) lists Novo as a compatible trainer too. You can of-course buy it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

To answer more generally than Vladimir, the question refers to a trainer which clamps the rear end of the bike from the sides. This style of trainer has been around for some time, and when it originated, bikes had quick release levers. Those have nuts on either side that trainers clamped around.

Since then, mountain and then most road bikes have evolved to use thru-axles. They are flush with the dropouts on one or both sides, so there is nothing for the type of trainer above to clamp to. Vladimir linked to a thru axle sold by Elite that has knobs on either side of the axle. If the trainer company does not sell thru axles like this, other interested cyclists can look for third party thru axles like the [Robert Axle Project](https://robertaxleproject.com/wind-trainer/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIv8ufxbHF9AIV_WpvBB38Hg_GEAAYASADEgISDfD_BwE).

Comment: That looks like a great website. Thanks for sharing.