# Is an Indoor Trainer Tyre Required with a Magnetic Powered Trainer

Tags: tire, trainer, indoor

If I buy [Elite Novo Force](https://www.elite-it.com/en/products/home-trainers/classic-trainers/novo-force), is an indoor trainer tyre like [Coperton](https://www.elite-it.com/en/products/home-trainers/ecosystem-accessories/coperton) **a must** to protect the longetivity of the rear tyre?

Is that product more towards MTBs to reduce the sound element while pedalling but still a good practice to be considered even for road bikes with slick tyres?

Comment: I don't bother with trainers preferring to ride in all weathers, but another option some people use is worn road tyres, perhaps ones they've booted (unlike me who seems to attract the wrong sort of failure) and no longer trust.  Stock tyres that came with bikes but don't suit the rider are another option

Comment: @ChrisH True. Good to keep in mind. However, I recently switched to a road bike and got nothing spare but thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use road tyres on turbo trainers, which I used to do many years back. The problem is that there is a lot of heat and often a lot of pressure at the contact point, so the tyre wears down a lot quicker than it would normally.
You also end up with a lot of tyre residue building up on the turbo trainer wheel, which you need to scrape off.

Turbo-trainer specific tyres are a lot harder wearing. They will last a lot longer and you won't have as much tyre residue to deal with.
One caveat is that some turbo-trainer specific tyres do have a soft layer that wears off first before exposing the harder material underneath.

As turbo-trainer specific tyres are hard-wearing it means they have very little grip and so shouldn't be used on the road.